# OnClick function not working with custom button Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I am passing the value of the button the user clicks on to an array with the following function.

```
 const [pizzaSize, setPizzaSize] = useState("Choose your Pizza Size");
  const [startPrice, setStartPrice] = useState(0);
  const addPizza = (e) => {
    setPizzaSize(e.target.name);
    setStartPrice(parseInt(e.target.value));
  };
```

I want to use a custom button component in order to have it toggle on and off, like I have already done with other buttons on the same page.

```
const ButtonClickable3 = (props) => {
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");
    const handleToggle = (e) => {
     setActive(!isActive);
     props.onClick(e)
    }; 
     return <button
               type="button"
               value={props.value}
               className={isActive ? "button btn fourth" : "button btn fourthActive"}
               onClick={handleToggle}
             >
              {props.name}
             </button>
   
   }
```

Finally I call the function as follows

```
<ButtonClickable3 name="test" value="5" onClick={(event) => addPizza(event)}></ButtonClickable3>
```

When I use a regular button the function works, so I am stumped as to why the custom one does not.

My custom buttons 1 and 2 are also working, but they are using a different function.
I have put my full code on a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-perlman-pqln8?file=/src/CYO.js).

 I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original `<button` has a `name` attribute, but the `<ButtonClickable3` does not. so:

```
setPizzaSize(e.target.name);
```

fails with the `ButtonClickable3`. You need:

```
return <button
               type="button"
               name={props.name}
               value={props.value}
```

inside `ButtonClickable3`.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy. A second pair of eyes really helps, Thank you.